# How can you add a CAGradientLayer to a cell in a tableview from within the cells' awakeFromNib() method?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have been adding CAGradient layers to cells using this code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as myCell

cell.mImageView.image = UIImage(named: scripts[indexPath.row].thumbnailImage)

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

if(cell.layer.sublayers.count == 2){ //This is to stop stacking gradient layers
  gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]
  gradientLayer.locations = [0.6, 1.0]
  gradientLayer.frame = cell.bounds
  cell.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, below: cell.mImageView.layer)
}
```

This is from within the tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath) method of my CustomTableViewController class.

I have a `myCell` class that I would much rather use to perform the gradient layout, but I cannot use this code or the `cell` object from within the `awakeFromNib()` method.

How can I insert this CAGradientLayer from within the `awakeFromNib` (or `init()`) method of the myCell class? The cell also contains a label and I would like to insert it beneath the label as well.

Comment: Why can't you use this code in awakeFromNib or the init method? What result does that give you if you try either of those?

Comment: @rdelmar When I use `self.layer.insertSublayer` or `self.layer.addSublayer` I get a runtime error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @rdelmar Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address = 0x7ff2038e31ff8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you would get that error. I tried a slight modification of your code (in the cell class), and it worked ok. Here it is,

```
class RDTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mImageView: UIImageView!

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.6, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, below: self.mImageView.layer)
    }
}
```

I assumed that you want the gradient at the bottom of the cell, and that did not happen with my cells (which had a height of 70) if I put the code in awakeFromNib.

Comment: Ok, so I copied your method out but for some reason the gradient isn't actually applied to the cell.

Comment: @A_toaster I modified it slightly, to put the code in didMoveToSuperview, but I don't know if that will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks heaps, your code worked when in `didMoveToSuperView`!
Any idea on why it didn't work with `awakeFromNib`?

Strangely enough, when I use `self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, below: self.nameLabel.layer)` the nameLabel still appears beneath the gradient. Very strange indeed

Comment: @A_toaster, did you confirm that awakeFromNib was called? Even if it was, the thing I noticed was that the size of the cell is not necessarily correct at the time awakeFromNib is called (it shows up as 320 x 44 no matter what simulator I'm using, and what cell height I've set in the table view controller).

Comment: Yeah, it definitely ran, but I guess the sizing is not performed until slightly after. Thanks again!